# Overlay Analysis in QGIS (or Preferably Python)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, overlay, parcel

I would like to perform an overlay analysis in Python or QGIS to output a list of each shapefile that falls within certain boundaries. I have unsuccessfully tried to use the Spatial Join, Intersect, and Union commands that were described in [this similar GIS Exchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/107318/53712).

For each parcel described in [this shapefile (links to download)](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/download/bytes/bk_mappluto_14v2.zip), I would like to see whether it exists within the regions of [this shapefile](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/download/bytes/nyc_freshzoning20151.zip).

Would you please point me in the right direction on how to do this? If there is a Python library that I can use, I would prefer that method.

Answer (score 3):

1) The easiest solution is to use the `processing` module in the QGIS Python console:

```py
import processing
processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation","BKMapPLUTO.shp","DCP_nyc_freshzoning.shp","['intersects']",0,"sum,mean,min,max,median",0,'result.shp')
```

2) Without a GIS, you can use [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) (read and write shapefiles as Python dictionaries) and [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) (geometries) -> look at [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc/103066#103066) and replace `within` by `intersects`. I follow here the same procedure.

a) The trivial solution: iterating through all the geometries (very longtime with your shapefiles...).

```py
from shapely.geometry import shape
import fiona
with fiona.open('BKMapPLUTO.shp') as input:
    schema = input.schema
    schema['properties']['NAME'] = 'str:30'
    meta = input.meta
    with fiona.open('DCP_nyc_freshzoning.shp') as regions:
       with fiona.open ('result2.shp', 'w', **meta) as output:
           for feat in input:
               poly1 = shape(feat['geometry'])
               for poly2 in regions:
                   if poly1.intersects(shape(poly2['geometry'])):
                        feat['properties']['NAME']=  poly2['properties']['NAME']
                        output.write(feat)
```

2) To accelerate the procedure, you can use a boundary spatial index  ([rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) here)

```py
regions = [pol for pol in fiona.open('DCP_nyc_freshzoning.shp')]
# creation of the spatial index
from rtree import index
idx = index.Index()
for pos, poly in enumerate(regions):
    idx.insert(pos, shape(poly['geometry']).bounds)

with fiona.open('BKMapPLUTO.shp') as input:
    schema = input.schema
    schema['properties']['NAME'] = 'str:30'
    meta = input.meta
    with fiona.open ('result2.shp', 'w', **meta) as output:
        for feat in input:
             poly = shape(feat['geometry'])
             for j in idx.intersection(poly.bounds):
                  if poly.intersects(shape(regions[j]['geometry'])):
                     feat['properties']['NAME']=  regions[j]['properties']['NAME']
                     output.write(feat)
```

3) You can do the same with `QgsSpatialIndex()` in the Python console of QGIS

```py
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for pos, poly in enumerate(regions):
    index.insertFeature(poly)
```

Comment: In the QGIS console, I tried the first solution by providing the absolute paths to the directories. It did not output any parcels. I can now get the Intersection and other built-in functions in QGIS to work (before I wasn't letting it load sufficiently, rookie mistake!!). Do you have any thoughts as to why it isn't working. I'm using the same exact code as before, except now I'm using a larger shapefile (representative of all NYC).