# Assigning an NTA code to a point feature class from a polygon feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, fields-attributes, feature-class

I have a point feature class and a polygon feature class (NTA - Neighborhood Tabulation Areas).  I want to assign each record in the point feature class an NTA that it falls into.  Also, neither of these feature classes has a common field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Intersect between the two layers will give you the NTA attributes on each of the points. This assumes you have a one polygon for each point relationship. If a point could fall in more than one polygon (unlikely given your data description), you'd need something different. Also, any points that do not fall in a polygon will be dropped. For other options and more detailed explanations, see my answer at [How to determine which polygons, if any, points fall within?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104124/).